# Android: is forcing to use ListView

Tags: java, android

I want to make a menu, which contains 4 different LinearLayouts.
Top one has title, second one has description, the third one has 3 ImageViews, which have event onClick, and the fourth one has a Button which also has onClick event.

Somehow, android doesn't like it, and forcing me to use ListView.

The exception message is: **java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'**

I have already tried to use ListView, and it didn't work as I expected. For example, the 3rd layout, which has 3 buttons, the events are not working for each ImageView, but instead on the row of the ListView.

What can be done?

Displaying my layouts xml files:

**options.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/optionsLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" android:layout_gravity="center">

    <include  layout="@layout/options_layout1" android:id="@+id/optionsLayout1" />
    <include  layout="@layout/options_layout2" android:id="@+id/optionsLayout2" />
    <include  layout="@layout/options_layout3" android:id="@+id/optionsLayout3" />
    <include  layout="@layout/options_layout4" android:id="@+id/optionsLayout4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**options_layout1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/optionsTitleLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/options" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

**options_layout2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/chooseThemeTitleLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/choose_theme" android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:layout_marginTop="70dip" />
```

**options_layout3.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/optionButtonsLayout" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/theme1Btn"
        android:background="@drawable/theme1_off" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip" />
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/theme2Btn" android:background="@drawable/theme2_off" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" />
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/theme2Btn"
        android:id="@+id/theme3Btn" android:background="@drawable/theme3_off" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**options_layout4.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/saveButtonLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/saveBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Save" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,
Henry.

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694923/what-can-i-do-about-this-null-pointer-exception/7694941#7694941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the xml, the problem is somewhere in the code. You use a specific class which expects an ID R.id.list to be in your layout. Probably your Activity still extends ListActivity? This Activity needs an R.id.list in it's layout.

Comment: That's correct. I have extended PreferenceActivity which extends ListActivity. I changed my code to extend Activity, and all worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a `ListActivity`? If so, just replace it for `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you extends your activity as ListActivity ,you have to listview with android:id="@android:id/list"

otherwise extends your activity as Activity and and get listview :
Listview list = (Listview) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
```